# Unable to locate element and click on button

Tags: selenium

```
<button ng-if="(trans_head == 'N') &amp;&amp; (totalDocValueCount != totalDocVerifiedCount) &amp;&amp; (document_name != 'Select Document')" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right right10 ng-scope" data-target="#verificationConfirmationWindow" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                Verify document
</button>
```

This is my HtML code. I tried to locate the "Verify document" button but unable to click and locate it.

I tried by XPath also and:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Above code is not giving any exception but no locating also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-success.btn-xs.pull-right.right10.ng-scope[type='submit']")));
button.click();
```

PS: If an element is inside `iframe`, then switch to it before doing action.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @PritiRaut, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Comment: if we need to click on same button for n no of time..again and again.. is there is any solution? or we need to add that code again

Comment: @PritiRaut, I did not understand you. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath : `//button[text()='Verify document']`

**Code**  : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Verify document']")).click();`

Comment: check the availability of web element and please check if it's in an iframe ?

Comment: Unable to locate element: //button[text()='Verify document']

Comment: check if it's in an iframe ?